# Possible to copy/move/etc multiple files of same base name via Windows CMD/.BAT?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am wondering if it is possible to accomplish the following, given some context and example.

I have files in "Server\Share\Folder\File##.ext"
Sometimes the "File##.ext" can be "File01.ext" through "File20.ext", and other times it may be "File01.ext" through "File40.ext"
Sometimes there are less of these files, sometimes there are more.

I want a batch file to take the files from "Server\Share\Folder\File##.ext" and move them to "Server\Share\OtherFolder\File##.ext". I know I can accomplish this easily with:

copy /y "Server\Share\Folder\File01.ext" "Server\Share\OtherFolder\File01.ext"

Then just add another line for each extra "File02.ext, File03.ext, etc., but I am wondering if it is possible to make it so that any file that resembles "File##.ext" can be included, so that no matter how many ## I have, it always works without issue.

Thanks in advance for any and all advice!

***EDIT***
Someone mentioned using Wildcards, but my question with that is - lets say those files are File01.ext through File05.ext, will it match what it finds to the newly moved file? Like will it find File01 from File?? on the source and Make it File01 from File?? at the destination?

Comment: How about `copy /y "Server\Share\Folder\File*.ext" "Server\Share\OtherFolder\"` ?

Comment: Will that take whatever file name it finds using the * for example File01.ext and name it the same on the destination?

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY for me, I replicated in a test environment and this does exactly what I need. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task with a `FOR`loop program in batch-file. 
You can also loop through the Commands using `:`  and variable name.
Combining these two would help you get what you want.

> We can help you with Ideas and little bit of the coding. But the **Efforts** must be done by you. So U can learn programming better

Comment: Can you provide an example possibly, given my context?